# Host Blazor Server in Web API Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Web API project and a Blazor Wasm Project that I want to host from that Web API project using the same port. But I cannot make it work.
When I launch the web api project it spins up but the blazor app is not.
I have configured the launchsettings, making sure the ports are matching, but I cannot make it work. I have considered changing from the wasm hosting model to the server hosting model.
Let me know if you need additional information.

Launch Settings in Web APi Project:

```
"DEV": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
```

LaunchSettings in Blazor project

```
      {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BlazorServerClient": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is when I tried using Blazor Server instead, but the launch settings is the same in my wasm project

If there is other (better) options by doing this differently i am open to suggestions, the goal is to host both the api and the blazor app from a single point using the same port.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample .

1.Publish your WebAssembly app to a folder .

2.locate your published file , which is `BlazorApp3\bin\Release\net7.0\browser-wasm\publish` , and copy the **wwwroot** file . Replace the wwwroot file (if not exists , create one) in your WebApi app with the wwwroot in publish .

3.Download the nudget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` and in your WebApi program.cs :

```
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();                     
app.UseRouting();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.Run();
```

4.Do not set to run on the same port in your **launchSettings.json** of two apps.

5.Start the WebApi app and when you run to the root url , Blazor will start and you can see

[image]
[image]